# Entity Framework - How to NOT update related objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I have the following simple Create method in my repository. The behaviour that I want to prevent is the insertion of related objects at the same time that the target object (OrderItem) is inserted.

In this case, the Order item has a reference property - Product. When the OrderItem record is created, so is a Product record.

How can I disassociate the two so that only the OrderItem  is inserted?

```
public OrderItem Create(OrderItem orderItem, int orderID)
{
    orderItem.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    orderItem.OrderID = orderID;

    this.DbContext.OrderItems.Add(orderItem);
    this.DbContext.SaveChanges();

    return orderItem;
}
```

Comment: so you want to save the product at a different time or not at all?

Comment: The product is saved at a later time, yes. The saving of the product requires special logic in this application, hence the separation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detach the Product property from the context:

```
this.DbContext.Entry(orderItem.Product).State = EntityState.Detached;
```